# Download and view pdf using Cordova plugins and Ionic 3 not working

Tags: android, ios, cordova, pdf, ionic-framework

Hello I am facing an issue while trying to open a pdf on mobile devices, using ionic 3. Basically I get the pdf from a web service and after decrypting the file, I ask if is being opened from a browser or from an application. If is being opened from the browser, I use in app browser to render pdf and it works like a charm, no problems there, but when is opened from a mobile device like an App I take a different approach, download the file and open it using

> Document Viewer plugin
>   File
>   File Transfer

here is some code, first we make the call to the web service and subscribe to the response:

```
clickBtn(e) {
 const loading = this.loadingController.create({
   content: ''
});
loading.present().then(() => {
  const productExtractsRq: ProductExtractsRq = this.extractRq;
  productExtractsRq.customer = this.bdbUtilsProvider.getCustomer();
  // get file from WEB SERVICE
  this.transactionsProvider.getProductExtracts(productExtractsRq).subscribe(
    (data) => {
      loading.dismiss();
      // CREATE THE PDF
      this.blob = this.createPdf(data);
      this.url = window.URL.createObjectURL(this.blob);
      // COMPARE WHICH PLATFORM IS ACCESSING THE APP
      if (this.platform.is('core') || this.platform.is('mobileweb')) {
        this.iab.create(this.url, '_system');
      } else {
        this.downloadAndOpenPdf(this.url);
      }
    },
    (ex) => {
      loading.dismiss();
      if (ex.status === 409) {
        this.tsErrorProvider.launchErrorModal(ex.error._error);
      } else {
        this.bdbModal.launchErrModal(
          'Ha ocurrido un error',
          'El extracto no se pudo generar, por favor intenta más tarde.',
          'Aceptar'
        );
      }
    }
  );
});
}
```

here is the method for when is opened by app:

```
downloadAndOpenPdf(url: string) {
let path = null;

if (this.platform.is('ios')) {
  path = this.file.documentsDirectory;
} else if (this.platform.is('android')) {
  path = this.file.dataDirectory;
}

// this.document.viewDocument(url, 'application/pdf', {});

const transfer = this.transfer.create();
transfer.download(url, path + 'myfile.pdf').then(entry => {
  toast.present();
  const _url = entry.toURL();
  this.document.viewDocument(_url, 'application/pdf', {});
})
.catch(err => {
  alert(JSON.stringify(err));
  toast.present();
  this.iab.create(url, '_blank');
});
}
```

and here is the create pdf method, which apparently works fine.

```
createPdf<Blob>(data: ProductExtractsRs) {
const bytes: string = atob(atob(data.binData));
const byteNumbers = new Array(bytes.length);
for (let i = 0; i < bytes.length; i++) {
  byteNumbers[i] = bytes.charCodeAt(i);
}
const byteArray = new Uint8Array(byteNumbers);
return new Blob([byteArray], { type: 'application/pdf' });
}
```

So whenever I try to open the pdf I get the error:

```
{
 "code":2,
 "source":"blob:file:///a44e17fc-1eb7-458a-9130-3d7b4f3a790b",
 "target": "file///data/user/0/io.ionic.starter/files/myfile.pdf",
 "http_status":null,
 "body": null,
 "exception": null
}
```

And nothing else happens, anyone can tell what am I doing wrong?, remember that the pdf opens with no problem using the in app browser on web app. Any hint will be highly appreciated !